# Most efficient way of checking if Date object and Calendar object are in the same month

Tags: java, performance, date, comparison, deprecated

I am working on a project that will run many thousands of comparisons between dates to see if they are in the same month, and I am wondering what the most efficient way of doing it would be.

This isn't exactly what my code looks like, but here's the gist:

```
List<Date> dates = getABunchOfDates();
Calendar month = Calendar.getInstance();
for(int i = 0; i < numMonths; i++) 
{
    for(Date date : dates)
    {
        if(sameMonth(month, date)
            .. doSomething
    }
    month.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
}
```

Creating a new `Calendar` object for every date seems like a pretty hefty overhead when this comparison will happen thousands of times, soI kind of want to cheat a bit and use the deprecated method `Date.getMonth()` and `Date.getYear()`

```
public static boolean sameMonth(Calendar month, Date date)
{
    return month.get(Calendar.YEAR) == date.getYear() && month.get(Calendar.MONTH) == date.getMonth();
}
```

I'm pretty close to just using this method, since it seems to be the fastest, but **is there a faster way?**  And **is this a foolish way**, since the `Date` methods are deprecated?  Note: This project will always run with Java 7

Comment: Where do you get the 'dates' from? If they are in a database, another alternative could be to make sure the field has a sane (date) type and simply use the database engine for filtering objects in the same month? You could even add indexes, cluster etc to make this blazingly fast.

Comment: I am getting them from a database, and each date is a key in a map, representing a month's worth of various kinds of data.  The database is grouping everything by month, but there are thousands of these individual 'reports'.  I'm thinking of your suggestion to return indexes rather than dates from the database, though.  That way, I never have to instantiate a Date object in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't comment on whether to use the deprecated methods, but if you choose not to there's no need to instantiate a new `Calendar` for every `Date` you check. Just use one other `Calendar` and call `setTime(date)` before the check (or one `Calendar` for every thread if you parallelize it).

As a side note, I do have to agree with ChristopheD's comment that this is something worthy of a database.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can define a static `DateFormat` to extract the month and year from `Date` and use both objects as date only.

```
    public static DateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateForm("MMyyyy");
    public static boolean sameMonth(Date date1, Date date2)
    {
      return formatter.format(date1).equals(formatter.format(date2));
    }
```

Comment: @PaulBellora: I think its of similar performance as one in the question but not using deprecated methods.